# How to enable sslv3 request in libcurl

Tags: linux, ssl, libcurl

How to enable the support of SSLV3 request in libcurl if it is disabled by default? I have found this on internet. https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2015-01/0005.html.

How to use the patch available in this site? Or if there is any other way to achieve this then please guide?

Comment: Why in the world would you want to enable a deprecated, unsecure, broken protocol like that?

Comment: There are lot of Debian Etch running devices which have OpenSSL version that only supports SSLV2 and SSLV3. It will require a lot of effort to update these devices for TLS requests so I am changing curl requests to support SSLV3.

Comment: Debian Etch in 2019? Oh my, you have a totally different problem...

Answer (score 4):

## SSLv3 is insecure

curl supports SSLv3 out of the box. Your SSL library may not though. I don't think any modern TLS library does. And if curl is built to support it, you must explicitly ask curl to allow it at run-time since the default will be TLS by default.

If you for example want to use with OpenSSL you need to build OpenSSL and explicitly ask it to enable SSLv3 in the config as otherwise it will not support SSLv3.

SSLv3 is inherently **insecure** and there's nothing we can do to fix that in the protocol. That's why everyone avoids touching it and have moved on. Going with SSLv3 in 2019 is a mistake. Don't go there. Argue with your boss, stand your ground.

Comment: Yes, we can set option of SSLV3 in curl but the version I am using does not support SSLV3 so I am asking how can I enable it. I have found some links related
https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2015-01/0005.html 
but I don't know how to use this patch.
Regarding argue with boss, I am working on it.

Comment: You don't need that patch, it is already in master. You need to build your own SSL library and then build the latest curl to use that.

Comment: By build do you mean install?

Comment: I mean build. Then install.

Comment: Can I enable TLS1.2 on libcurl v7.15.5?

Comment: Anything is possible, but that would take backporting work since that came many years before TLS1.2 existed. I would strongly recommend against that. Use a modern libcurl version.

Comment: The reasons of running this version is that there are number of devices which have Debian Etch installed and this is the latest version of libcurl that they support. So I have to make TLS1.2 request enable for them as this is my requirement

Comment: It's not. You can easily build and run the latest curl on any Debian release you can find.

Comment: can you guide how I am new to linux as apt-get install only install openssl v0.98 and libcurl v7.15